# local storage for google map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, local-storage

How do I incorporate localStorage in my code? I have a show and hide button on my google map that will Hide and Show a marker array. I need to store the values in  localStorage when the button is clicked.

What I have so far:

```
var testbtn = document.getElementById('test1');
var testbtn2 = document.getElementById('test2');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(testbtn, 'click', hide);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(testbtn2, 'click', show); 

function hide() {
    set_speed_camera(null);
    localStorage.setItem("hide_speed_camera", "true");       
}

function show() {
    set_speed_camera(map);
    localStorage.setItem("show_speed_camera", "true");
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("show_speed_camera"))) {
       set_speed_camera(map);
       alert('testing..Show')    
    }
}); 

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hide_speed_camera"))) {
        set_speed_camera(null);
        alert('testing..Hide')
        localStorage.removeItem('hide_speed_camera');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one obvious issue, which is that you are using `localStorage.getItem` to get the *stringified* boolean. Instead, cast a `JSON.parse` to your `getItem`:

```
var testbtn = document.getElementById('test1');
var testbtn2 = document.getElementById('test2');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(testbtn, 'click', hide);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(testbtn2, 'click', show); 


function hide() {    
    set_speed_camera(null);
    localStorage.setItem("hide_speed_camera", "true");
}

function show() {
    set_speed_camera(map);
    localStorage.setItem("show_speed_camera", "true");
}
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("show_speed_camera"))) {    
    set_speed_camera(map);
}
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hide_speed_camera"))) {
    set_speed_camera(null);
}
```

---

```
> Boolean("true")
true
> Boolean("false")
true
```

Thus, unless you use a `JSON.parse`, the result of the `getItem` will always be `true`.

Comment: ok i got it working by adding localStorage.clear(); to both the functions, Would this be the correct way? have update the question.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage stores everything as strings.  You need to check what the current setting is in its string form.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("show_speed_camera") === "true") {
    set_speed_camera(map);     
}

if(localStorage.getItem("hide_speed_camera") === "true") { 
    set_speed_camera(null); 
}
```

Also, you have two stringified booleans controlling the same functionality.  Perhaps instead of having both a `show_speed_camera` and a `hide_speed_camera` stored in localStorage, just have a `showing_speed_camera`, like this:

```
function hide() {
       set_speed_camera(null);
       localStorage.setItem("showing_speed_camera", "false");      
}

function show() {
      set_speed_camera(map);
      localStorage.setItem("showing_speed_camera", "true");
}


if(localStorage.getItem("showing_speed_camera") === "true") {
    set_speed_camera(map);     
}

if(localStorage.getItem("hide_speed_camera") === "false") { 
    set_speed_camera(null); 
}
```